# ParallelTable and DistributeDefinitions

Tags: parallelization

I have a function in the following form:

```
function[...] := With[
  {...},
  Table[
    anotherfunction[i, j, ...],
    {i, ...},
    {j, ...},
    ...
  ]
]
```

If I'd like to replace `Table` with `ParallelTable`, do I need to put `` DistributeDefinitions["Global`"] `` somewhere? If yes, where? (Before `With`, before `ParallelTable`, or before calling `function`?)

`anotherfunction` is defined globally, and uses other global variables.

Comment: I added the backtick.  Click the edit link and see the source on how to do it (you need to surround the code with $n+1$ backticks if you want to include $n$ backticks).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ParallelTable` will automatically distribute the definitions of symbols used in the body of the table, as well as any dependencies, in version 8 and later.   It is not necessary to use `DistributeDefinitions` with `ParallelTable` in these versions.

Note that `ParallelEvaluate` does *not* automatically distribute definitions like `Parallelize`, `ParallelTable`, `ParallelMap`, `ParallelDo`, etc. do.  You do need to use `DistributeDefinitions` if you rely on `ParallelEvaluate`, however, you do not need to distribute the definitions of all symbols.  Just distribute the symbol that you are actually using, `anotherfunction` in this case.  `DistributeDefinitions` is smart enough to auto-distribute all the dependencies as well (unless you do something unusual such as converting strings to symbol names).

Comment: +1. Also note from the documentation: "DistributeDefinitions applies itself recursively to any symbols appearing in the definitions of the symbols  s_i."

Comment: I'm not sure the opening sentence is correct, or DistributeDefinitions would be of very-corner-case usefulness only. As a simple counterexample, try ``BeginPackage["Test`"]; Test`f = Function[x, $KernelID]; EndPackage[]; ParallelTable[f[x], {x, 8}]``, where the table is obviously returning the `f[x]` unevaluated for the master kernel to rework. Adding ``DistributeDefinitions["Test`"]`` makes the table return a correct list of nonzero IDs.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty [You know why that is](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111711/12). Describing every corner case is not always the most useful answer to a question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Apologies, I didn't mean to come across anywhere near aggressive. My point was that it would be helpful to add '(excluding functions in packages)', or something similar, just as a note to new users that there are special considerations in place if packages or other contexts are in use. To be frank, though, I still don't fully understand what does and does not get distributed by default by `ParallelTable`, so I didn't want to jump into the wiki and write something that's wrong. If you feel that it's too much load on an introductory answer, though, that's still fine =).